# Crash course on Sonar

Tags: signal-analysis, reference-request, array-signal-processing, sonar

I have some experience in Signal processing and a lot more in solving numerically the electromagnetic field integral equations using Matlab and C++.

Now I am curious about the Sonar (e.g., underwater) and wanted to give a solid introduction to this field and write some Matlab/C++ code to understand the concepts.

Any recommendations on where to start that give intermediate to advance knowledge in that field?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start, but try [this book by Hodges.](https://ia600202.us.archive.org/19/items/Underwater_Acoustics_Analysis_Design_and_Performance_of_Sonar_By_Richard_P._Hodg/Underwater_Acoustics_Analysis_Design_and_Performance_of_Sonar_By_Richard_P._Hodges.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: Thank you and books on Sonar are kind of very expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two main books that I've seen most often are:

Richard Neilsen - Sonar Signal Processing see [here](https://www.amazon.ca/Sonar-Signal-Processing-Richard-Nielsen/dp/0890064539)
which covers: Beamforming, LOFAR, DEMON processing, active and passive systems.

William Burdic - Underwater Acoustic System Analysis see [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008WDLHXG), which covers more of the passive and active sonar equations (noise and reverberation limited).

The Hodges book, mentioned by Peter, is also good. It covers some aspects not mentioned in the other two e.g. Lloyd's mirror and target motion analysis.

I've yet to see anything that really cover Sonobuoy processing - you can find some information in published papers but it is scattered.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: I hope you find them useful. The Neilsen book can be hard to find.

Comment: Both of the books costs nearly 200 euros and its kind of very expensive. But the Peter K's book is nice. Basically its writes the Sonar equations and each chapter derives the components of the Sonar equation analytically.

Comment: If you have access to a technical university library, they would likely have a copy. I would check them out there first to see if they have what you are looking for before purchasing them.

Comment: I was curious about the subject and as well as engineering challenges. Recently saw a documentary where they showed 3D-pictures of ocean maps and I was bit stunned and as well as inspired to look into the subject.

I have some experience in linear algebra and have implemented GMRES, an iterative solver for Fast Multipole Method.